# IPv6 DHCP is disconnected from the Internet

Tags: networking, macos, ipv6, ipv4

A friend's MacOS has this configuration and it is connected to the Internet:

```
IPv4 DHCP
IPv6 disabled
```

And then he changed it to

```
IPv4 disabled
IPv6 DHCP
```

In the following several seconds, this PC is still able to access Internet (website in browser responds to fresh), but during this time, PC shows "disconnect from Internet" and kept trying to reconnect.
And after that, PC is cut from Internet (website in browser does not respond to fresh).

I know ARP/RARP DHCP DNS, and it could be somewhere something cached. Then I wonder what protocol server must use IPv4 and does not accept IPv6 in his ISP network, that makes OS think it is disconnected from the Internet.

Comment: Maybe you are not receiving an IPv6 address via DHCP.

Comment: for windows, it tries to reach a Microsoft domain and if it's not reachable it tells you that it's disconnected

Comment: The problem might be with the router not supporting IPv6 DHCP.